# What should I do if my (Exynos SM-N900)Note 3 has bootloop?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-note-3, hard-reset

I have experienced bootloop, it only shows SamSung Logo... And if I download ROM from SAMobile, how do I know if that Rom is not corrupted. Also, how do I know if Odin is stuck/hang or not? Because I thought it hanged so I pulled the cable and it showed crappyKies thing ( when I flashed CFAutoRoot ) then I bring that to Samsung and they fixed it (before root) now I am rooted.. What to do? I am scared

Comment: You can check the MD5 sum of your downloaded ROM vs the one on their server, the'll give you the value and there's tons of programs and even websites to check MD5. If they match, your file is not corrupt. Don't forget to wipe the device before flashing the ROM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your phone hangs at the Boot-Logo (Note 3), then you have not flashed the ROM the right way.

If it hangs at the Boot-Anination (Samsung), you probably forgot wiping caches and maybe the data partition.